# Special characters like ✓ are not being saved in text fields

Tags: database, fieldtypes

we have just noticed that characters like ✓ are being saved in the title field but not in plain text fields regardless of the database type (PostgreSQL / MySQL) or field type in the database (text, varchar etc.).

Thanks for your help,
Lars

Answer (score 0):

The Plain Text field only supports emojis that the [LitEmoji](https://github.com/elvanto/litemoji) library supports:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/PlainText.php#L252

Unfortunately, ✓ currently isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks Brad, any plans on changing that? I just wonder because the Unicode characters are being saved in the title field which is of the same type as a plain text field.